wxWidgets vcpkg link errors
I installed vcpkg and then ran the command vcpkg install wxwidgets. This has successfully installed wxwidgets. To test it, I have the following files:
wxsample.cpp
class MyApp : public wxApp
{
public:
    virtual bool OnInit();
};


class MyFrame : public wxFrame
{
//Contents
};


wxIMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp);

//rest of the code

CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.27.2)

project(Hello)

include(C:/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake)

add_executable(Hello wxsample.cpp)

find_package(wxwidgets REQUIRED COMPONENTS core base)

include(${wxWidgets_USE_FILE})
target_include_directories(Hello PRIVATE ${wxWidgets_INCLUDE_DIRS})

target_link_libraries(Hello PRIVATE ${wxWidgets_LIBRARIES} )

The cpp file compiles fine but I get the following error:
MSVCRT.lib(exe_main.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol main referenced in function "int __cdecl __scrt_common_main_seh(void)" (?__scrt_common_main_seh@@YAHXZ)
I am fairly new to vcpkg ecosystem so any ideas what I might be missing?

Try adding WIN32 to make it a windows application not a console one, add_executable(Hello WIN32 ...), the error you see is simply "main not defined", alternatively there is another macro for console applications in wxwidgets if that's what you want.

@AhmedAEK, Yes, WIN32 was the problem. Now it is fixed and working as expected, many thanks!
